# Render output difference cause

Tags: opengl, shaders, rendering, glsl, lighting

There are two 3D applications compared side by side:

[image: Comparison 1: 3DBenchy]

[image: Comparison 2: Yennefer]

I'm looking for difference cause. These might be the cause, but I'm not sure:

- Color
- Lighting
- Shading code (GLSL)
- ?

Can anybody help me with detecting the difference cause?

Comment: Yes, all of these things you listed cause a difference in appearance. I'd hesitate a bit on "light", since the renderer on the left does not appear to be attempting to simulate the play of light on the surface at all, though I guess the absence of a directional light is still a difference. I don't think "yes" is a very useful answer for you though. What do you hope to DO with this information? Ask about how to do that instead.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks. I intend to make the left output look more like the right one.

Comment: Sounds like you should tell us how you're generating the left output then, so we can show you what parts you need to change.

Comment: A possible mistake: you calculate light in SRGB-space, not linear-space.

Comment: Well the shading code is *everything* so yes, that causes the difference. (Colour and lighting are just parts of the shading code)

Comment: @user253751 Thanks, I'm going to post my shading code. I cannot figure out what shading code changes are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem got resolved by changing [Phong shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading) parameters of `ambient` color, `diffuse` color, `specular` color, `shininess` and `alpha`.

---

Previously these values were used:

```
// Colors components from 0 to 1 along with their corresponding hexagonal
ambient  RGB = (0.259, 0.522, 0.957) or #4285F4
diffuse  RGB = (0.49, 0.49, 0.49) or #7d7d7d
specular RGB = (1, 1, 1) or #ffffff
shininess    = 0.0
```

Result:

[image: Before]

---

Replaced the above values with these:

```
// Color components from 0 to 1
ambient RGBA  = (0.015135135135135, 0.047675675675676, 0.07, 1.0)
diffuse RGBA  = (0.211891891891892, 0.66745945945946, 0.98, 0.5)
specular RGBA = (0.003027027027027, 0.009535135135135, 0.014, 1.0)
shininess     = 150.0
```

Result:

[image: After]